# Properties of a determinant and the elementary matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Switching Rows or columns: $\det(B)=-\det(A)$
2. Multiplying a row or column by c: $\det(B)=c\times\det(A)$
3. Adding a multiple or a row [column] to another row [column]: $\det(B)=\det(A)$

The book says that these three rules define the determinant, but of course 2 and 3 define 1. Why is it necessary to include the first one. The book goes on to name several secondary widely used properties of determinants such as $\det(AB)=\det(A)\times\det(B)$. Why isn't the usual treatment to place rule 1 as a secondary property? Furthermore, why is it even considered an elementary operation? I have checked several sources and they all agree that there are three properties and three types of elementary matrices. I cant find even one that agrees with the two rule case.

Comment: It would make more sense to define the determinants via wedge products, show that it's multiplicative, and then derive the three properties above trivially.

Comment: at first $\det(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is [an alternating multilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form) $(\mathbb{R}^n)^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and really nothing complicated here. It just means that it is linear in each $a_i$, and that switching $a_i$ and $a_j$ adds a minus sign

Comment: "But of course 2 and 3 define 1": what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I guess he is refering to the fact that elementary row operations of the first kind (switching two rows) can be accomplished by using elementary row operations of the second kind (multiplying a row with a nonzero scalar) and third kind (adding a multiple of a row to another row). Hence it sufficies to require conditions 2 and 3 for the determinant, and condition 1 follows.

Comment: Can it, though? It depends what you mean by the third kind

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Yes I am referring to the fact that switching rows can be accomplished by multiplication and addition. [a;b;c]-->[a;b+c;c]-->[a;b+c;c-(b+c)]-->[a;b+c;-b]-->[a;c;-b]-->[a;c;b]

Comment: The first condition is indeed redundant. Your book is unusual, not because it has a redundant condition, but because it is missing a defining condition: $\det(I)=1$.

Comment: @MikeK never notice that before... interesting